# I can not check the extension of a file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input file type and will seek the extension of the file to verify that it is not jpg, png, or empty but it always gives me error(always enters if) when I add the various conditions in the if.

```
var file = $("input[name=logo]", "#form").val();
var extension = file.replace(/^.*\./, '');
console.log(extension);
if (extension !== "jpg" || extension !== "png" || extension !== "") {
    $('.error-message').css({
        'display': 'block'
    });
    $(".error-message span").html('Ups! Please insert a png or jpg file!');
    $('.error-message').fadeIn('slow', function () {
        $('.error-message').delay(7000).fadeOut('slow');
    });
    return false;
}
```

thanks to all

Comment: "*gives me an error*". Okay? Care to elaborate?

Comment: give me error always enters if

Comment: you realize that your if condition is ALWAYS true right?  Did you mean to use && instead of ||?

Comment: i try if((extension !== "jpg") || (extension !== "png") || (extension !== "")) but does not work

Comment: @jgitter: No, he doesn't realize it. That's why he's asking the question.

Comment: yes. I want to check if it is not empty OR jpg OR png

Comment: input.files[n].name is a better way to get the filename than using value, which won't work for more than one file...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let see you condition :

```
(extension !== "jpg" || extension !== "png" || extension !== "")
```

Something is wrong there...

If one of these three is `true`, then go on. If extension is `jpg`, then it can't be `png` so the condition is true.

No matter what you do, you condition is true.

You see the problem? You have the wrong operator. Try :

```
(extension !== "jpg" && extension !== "png" && extension !== "")
```

[JSFiddle demonstrating the code snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/YuJLN/)

Comment: but with && will check if the extension is the 3 conditions at the same time, right? 
with | | checks if the extension is one of the 3 conditions, right?

Comment: you right! if i do with && (AND) work :). i understand, thanks

Answer (score 1):

So, let's examine this line:

`(extension !== "jpg" || extension !== "png" || extension !== "")`

This is equivalent to:

`!(extension === "jpg" && extension === "png" && extension === "")`.

This might make it a little bit easier to see that this will always be true. `extension` can't equal all three of those things.

What you really want is

`(extension !== "jpg" && extension !== "png" && extension !== "")`

Comment: Hello, I'm De Morgan's Law.  Have we met?

Comment: I couldn't remember what it was called, but yes.